# Volere bene vs amare

Tags: difference, synonym

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/volere_bene says that "volere bene" can mean:

- to be affectionate to someone
- to feel affection or love for someone
- to care for/about (literally, to wish good to)
- to be fond of

It also provides two examples:

- Ti voglio bene - I love you.
- Voglio bene a Marco - I love Marco.

I see all of those definitions above as synonyms, except "to feel love". In English, "love" is certainly stronger than being affectionate, caring or being fond of. If "volere bene" can cover such a wide range of feelings, some questions arise:

- Can the former be used to describe love in any kind of relationship (eg love of a mother for her son, love of a wife/fiancée/girlfriend for her husband/fiancé/boyfriend) ?
- What is the difference between "volere bene" and "amare" ?

Comment: I agree with Charo. I'm closing it as a duplicate. If you don't feel it is a duplicate, please edit the question to make clear what else is needed in an answer.

Comment: I agree that this is a duplicate. For some odd reason, the inline search didn't find the older question when I was typing the title. Maybe because one uses infinitive verbs and the other one the same verbs in the present tense.